# Apache port forward

Tags: apache, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have apache couchDB active on http://localhost:5984/ which i need to access at http://localhost:80/couch/. I need to setup a reverse proxi for this. Need help with the configuration settings.

PS: Whats the best resource to learn about apache?

Answer (score 28):

## Setting up the proxy

To set up a reverse-proxy with Apache2, you first need to enable the Apache proxy module and  virtualhosts. 
To enable the proxy module (mod_proxy), edit the Apache configuration file (Apache/conf/httpd.conf) and uncomment the following lines:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
```

You then need to enable VirtualHosts. To do this, just uncomment the following line from the same configuration file:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Finally, you need to edit Apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and write in it the proxy directives.
From the information you gave, they should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin ******
  DocumentRoot "******"
  ServerName *****

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off

  ProxyPass /couch/ http://127.0.0.1:5984/
  ProxyPassReverse /couch/ http://127.0.0.1:5984/
</VirtualHost>
```

(+ some mLog directives and a few others).

-> Apache restart -> profit.

## Learning Apache

You should have a look at the official documentation on the [Apache official website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) or [Apachetutor.org](http://www.apachetutor.org/), though Google is, and always will be, everyone's friend.

Comment: Hi, can you update theanswer according to apache2 ?

Comment: Hi, the answer is already intended for Apache2. Anything I can help you with?

Comment: I think he's referring to the fact that there is no "httpd.conf" file in a normal apache2 install on a modern linux install, say, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: whoever ends up here for this awesome answer saving one time and stress energy, might also be interested in how to activate those modules on ubuntu: `a2enmod proxy`,
`a2enmod proxy_http`,
`a2enmod unique_id`, `sudo apachectl -k restart`